# Convex piecewise linear functions - partitioned vs max representation

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, convex-geometry

I know that convex piecewise linear function $f$ can be defined in two closely related ways -

1. There exist $Q \subseteq P(X)$ s.t. $\bigcup Q = X$ and on every $A \in Q$ the function is linear ([Example](https://www.emis.de/journals/BAG/vol.43/no.1/b43h1ovc.pdf)).
2. There exist a set $\{(a_1,b_1),\ldots,(a_m,b_m)\}$ s.t. $f(x) = \max_{i\in[m]} a_i^T x + b_i$ ([Example](http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/ee236a/lectures/pwl.pdf)).

It makes sense that if $Q$ is a partition of $X$ it should be that $|Q| = m$ but I can't seem to prove it. Is my guess correct?

Comment: The $i$-th set of the partition is the one where the $i$-th function realizes the maximum. You might want to specify how you want to handle special cases such as when two functions are equal or when some function is redundant, but generally you are right.

Comment: I think the redundancy can be treated in two ways -
1. Change the equality with inequality
2. Specify that $f|_{A}$ is not the same for every two distinct subsets (in the sense of their extension to the whole space)

Comment: Is it that straightforward? The proof I know just shows that the epigraph is a polyhedron and as such can be represented as a max of affine functions but I can't seem to find the quantification. Maybe because the text wanted to avoid dealing with the cases you mentioned.

Comment: The first 'definition' does not guarantee convexity.